# Calling smartcontract functons as a string in web3.js

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js

Instead of calling a smart contract function like this

```
//assuming the name of the contract function is called "balanceOf"
contract.methods.balanceOf("0x", "0x").call(err, balance) => {
      console.log({err, balance});
})
```

Is it possible to call like this, instead:

```
var funcName = "balanceOf";
var parameter = "0x, 0x";
contract.methods.funcName(parameter).call(err, balance) => {
     console.log({err, balance}];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects in javascript can be accessed like an array by using the keys as indexes. So in your case it would be:

```
var funcName = "balanceOf";
var parameter = "0x, 0x";
contract.methods[funcName]("0x", "0x").call(err, balance) => {
   console.log({err, balance}];
})
```

But the way you passing the parameter is not going to work like that. You are just passing a string as a parameter. Think of it like passing parameters to any other function.

Comment: I tried that and I am getting an error saying contract.methods is not a function.